# Warning while dismissing and presenting FullScreen ModalViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, compiler-warnings, dismiss

I have `SplitViewController` project. In the detail's pane (right side), in the method -`viewDidAppear`, I have this code:

```
login.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
login.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

In the "login" `ViewController` I have a button that when is clicked, goes to this method:

```
-(void)registerEvent{
NSLog(@"registerEvent");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
[_delegate dismissLogin];
}];
}
```

And in my delegate `ViewController` (the `detailViewController`) method, I have this code:

```
-(void)dismissLogin{
ViewControllerRegister * registerForm = [ViewControllerRegister new];
[registerForm setDelegate:self];

registerForm.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

registerForm.modalTransitionStyle = transition;

[self presentViewController:registerForm animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is, if I change the modal presentation style to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, the compiler gives me NO warning and the `registerForm ViewController` is presented. But with `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`, the compiler gives me this warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    while a presentation is in
>   progress!

I have already tried to use `performSelector` with a delay of 0.4 and still not solve the problem.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this means that your view is already presenting something and it cannot present another view on the top of it.

Comment: Thank's. I found that when we present a VC with UIModalPresentationFullScreen, when you dismiss the VC, the parent VC start within the method ViewDidLoad. But if you use some other UIModelPresentations, (ex: UIModelPresentationFormSheet), the parent VC don't init with ViewDidLoad.

Comment: And that's because presenting on full screen mode takes over the whole screen, it does need to call the viewDidLoad on the parent when it is being dismissed because it needs to redraw the whole screen again. I'm glad I could help!